# How to disable usb automount in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: automount, usb-drive

How to completely disable automount of any USB HDD?
I would prefer mount them via the `sudo mount /dev/sde8 /mnt/...` method.

I have tried to write an udev rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-no-automount.rules`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="0"
```

but have not helped.